# Extract the n lowest sums from combinations of elements from m arrays for huge datasets

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, ranking

Let's say you have a number of unsorted arrays containing integers. Your job is to make sums of the arrays. The sums have to contain exactly one value from each array, i.e. (for 3 arrays)

```
sum = array1[2]+array2[12]+array3[4];
```

Goal: You should output the 20 combinations that generate the lowest possible sums.

The solution below is off-limits as the algorithm needs to be able to handle 10 arrays that can contain a huge number of integers. The following solution is way too slow for larger number of arrays:

```
//You already have int array1, array2 and array3
int top[20];
for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
   top[i] = 1e99;

int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<array1.size(); i++)      //One for loop per array is trouble for 
   for(int j=0; j<array2.size(); j++)   //increasing numbers of arrays
      for(int k=0; k<array3.size(); k++)
      {
         sum = array1[i] + array2[j] + array3[k];
         if (sum < top[19])
            swapFunction(sum, top); //Function that adds sum to top
                                    //and sorts top in increasing order
      }

printResults(top); // Outputs top 20 lowest sums in increasing order
```

What would you do to achieve correct results more efficiently (with a lower Big O notation)?

Comment: Start by sorting the three arrays

Comment: Nope not homework. A simplification of a process in a software I'm developing. I presented the problem like this to make it more readable. (Also I'm a teacher so that may be why it smells like homework) ;)

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be found by considering how to find the absolute lowest sum, and how to find the 2nd lowest sum and so on.

As you only need 20 sums at most, you only need the lowest 20 values from each array at most. I would recommend using `std::partial_sort` for this.

The rest should be able to be accomplished with a priority_queue in which each element contains the current sum and the indicies of the arrays for this sum.  Simply take each index of indicies and increase it by one, calculate the new sum and add that to the priority queue.  The top most item of the queue should always be the one of the lowest sum.  Remove the lowest sum, generate the next possibilities, and then repeat until you have enough answers.

Assuming that the number of answers needed is much less than Big O should be predominately be the efficiency of partial_sort (N + k*log(k)) * number of arrays

Here's some basic code to demonstrate the idea.  There's very likely ways of improving on this.  For example, I'm sure that with some work, you could avoid adding the same set of indicies multiple times, and there by eliminate the need for the do-while pop.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i++)
{
    auto b = arrays[i].begin();
    partial_sort(b, b + numAnswers, arrays[i].end());
}

struct answer
{
    answer(int s, vector<int> i)
        : sum(s), indices(i)
    {
    }

    int sum;
    vector<int> indices;

    bool operator <(const answer &o) const
    {
        return sum > o.sum;
    }
};

auto getSum =[&arrays](const vector<int> &indices) {
    auto retval = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i++)
    {
        retval += arrays[i][indices[i]];
    }
    return retval;
};

vector<int> initalIndices(arrays.size());

priority_queue<answer> q;
q.emplace(getSum(initalIndices), initalIndices );

for (auto i = 0; i < numAnswers; i++)
{
    auto ans = q.top();
    cout << ans.sum << endl;

    do
    {
        q.pop();
    } while (!q.empty() && q.top().indices == ans.indices);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ans.indices.size(); i++)
    {
        auto nextIndices = ans.indices;
        nextIndices[i]++;
        q.emplace(getSum(nextIndices), nextIndices);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. One small thing. If there are a lot of arrays then Big O would be time complexity of partial sort * number of arrays

Comment: True.  I'll fix that.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but consider this case:
Array1: 1,2,3
Array2: 2,3,4
Array3: 5,7,9

The first 3 sums we would get are 8, 9, 9. Meaning that if we set the second sum (1,3,5 or 2,2,4) as a starting point in the next step we will get problems. We cannot iterate forward from either one as a starting point since in case of 1,3,5, we must decrease the index of the second array as we increase the index of the first array to get 2,2,4 (the third lowest number).

Comment: @user2820246 yes, you're right. The algorithm is flawed after the sort. Ill have to think about it some more but a priority queue of sums trying to build the next possibilities from each of the arrays and eliminating duplicates answers is my first thought.

Comment: In the real code I need those duplicates as each array will affect a statistical value with different magnitude.

Comment: @user2820246 I've fixed the 2nd half of the algorithm and provided some example code.